# Managing Parse _Installation class after user deletes and reinstalls app

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform

So we have been having some issues with people not getting push notifications with our app.

What we found is when a user deletes and reinstalls the app while giving us Push Permissions another it creates another row in the _Installation class.

If we manually delete all the rows and the user installs the app and gives enables push, pushes are now sent to the user.

So the question is what is the best way to deal with this scenario to make sure that everyone only has one row in the _Installation class after installing or reinstalling.

Im trying this cloud function however its not returning any results even though in the DB it has extra rows for that user.

``

```
  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {

  var userId = request.object.get("user").id;
  console.log("user id = " + userId)

  query = new Parse.Query("_Installation");
  query.equalTo("user", {__type: "Pointer", className: "User", objectId: userId})

  query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(installations) {  
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + installations.length + " item");
      console.log(installations[0])
      console.log(installations)
      console.log('worked');
      response.success("The user has been authorized.");
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('failed')
      response.error("user authorization failed");
    });

});
```

``

console log from parse

`Feb 20 17:09:33 likemoji-stage app/web.1:  user id = t6yQIXiwvG 
Feb 20 17:09:33 likemoji-stage app/web.1:  Successfully retrieved 0 item 
Feb 20 17:09:33 likemoji-stage app/web.1:  undefined 
Feb 20 17:09:33 likemoji-stage app/web.1:  [] 
Feb 20 17:09:33 likemoji-stage app/web.1:  worked`

Comment: I'm trying this but not receiving any results back even though in that class it clearly has extra rows.

Answer (score 1):

Ok incase anyone runs into this issues, this is how I solved it.  There may be other ways to do this.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
  // get the parse user object to use in the query below
  var user = request.object.get("user")
  // actual query
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation)
  query.equalTo("user", user)
  query.descending("createdAt")  
  query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) {                 
    if(typeof results !== 'undefined' && results.length > 0) {
      return Parse.Object.destroyAll(results, {useMasterKey: true});
    }
  }).then(function() {
      // Done
      //console.log('finished')
  }, function(error) {
      // Error
      //console.log('failed')
  });
});
```